# error when launching image library in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am trying to lauch the image library with a package called react-native-image-picker:

```
function launchLibrary(fun) {

     let options = {
        storageOptions: {
         skipBackup: true,
         path: 'images',
      },
     };

    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        alert(response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        console.log(source);
        console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response));
        fun(response);
      }
    });
};
```

Then when the function gets executed, I get the following response:

```
 response {"errorMessage":"Activity error","errorCode":"others"}
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The Google Play store no longer accepts builds targeting SDK < 30 so I managed to get it working with a different work around.

I updated `react-native-image-picker` to version "^4.7.0" and the error went away, but note that `launchImageLibrary` response may now contain an array of "assets" with image data, rather than including the image data right within the response object.

After updating, replacing `response.uri` with `response.assets[0].uri` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I changed compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 30 to the 29 in
`build.gradle` , depending on that answer:
https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1600

```
 compileSdkVersion = 29
 targetSdkVersion = 29
```

and it worked normally after that.